# Suggested edit by same person different account

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, duplicate-accounts

I recently came across this [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8308082) which appears to be from the same user for separate accounts based on:

- similar user name ("Jhony" vs "Jhony Duenas") and  profile picture,
- comment for the suggest edit was

> adding the code from the link previously referenced as suggested

I guessing that this is the same user trying to improve his answer but from a different account.  Of course, since it's not the same account, the edit turned into a suggested edit, which would award the other account 2 rep.  Last I checked, both accounts "were seen" within 24 hours of now.

Ignoring the fact that I feel the suggested edit is possible plagiarism from another SE site, what is the right thing to do here?  Basically, if the edit had been something definitely approvable, what action(s) should I take?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It's actually common. Someone managed to become disenfranchised from their account and didn't realize it, so they ended up creating a new one and suggesting an edit on their own post.

There's a very good chance the system will just merge them automatically, but if you want to point it out to someone [feel free to contact us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) and let us know. You can also leave a comment to them along the lines of:

```
Looks like you accidentally created two accounts. You can [contact the team](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) to have them merged, which will allow you to regain direct editing privileges on your contributions.
```

We're getting *pretty* good at finding / merging these behind the scenes, but if you have a few seconds more to spare, that's what you can do :)

Comment: Ok account merging seems like a good solution.  For this specific instance, the timestamps are a little weird.  Both accounts are at least 8 months old, and both were active today.  Of course, it's still entirely possible the user is trying to merge them manually or something like that.  It's just weird that the duplicate account is really old and both accounts are "active".

Comment: They very well may be going through the merge process. Some folks also use multiple computers and are completely unaware that they're logged in with two different accounts, especially when the avatar is the same - that's why we're getting quite good at detecting and fixing that for them pretty silently.

Comment: Ok thanks for your advice.   I'll leave that comment for the user and call it good.

Comment: Here's another one:  http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11973624

Comment: Another one https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22523593

Comment: @jontro Thanks! Spaghettified at the event horizon .. err .. I mean ... merged!