# Handling edits from what looks like the OP but is from a randomly-generated anonymous user

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Occasionally, I see a few edits made by an anonymous user823964 sort of account on a question where it looks like something only the OP would know, like a followup with more information. Should we reject those, or just allow? Maybe there's some auth issue going on or the user forgot to or could not log in on a different computer.

**Update**:

Maybe wasn't clear; I'm not talking about all edits, just edits changing substantial content of the question as though it was the OP without the OP's username.

Comment: Sometimes, the OP will forget their login info or something similar. I've run into this before and that was the most likely situation.

Comment: Related: [Suggested edit by same person different account](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295938/suggested-edit-by-same-person-different-account)

Answer (score -2):

Who *cares* if it's an anonymous person or some other person that's edited the post?  The system even makes specific allowances for this behavior.

In all honesty, treat it like any run-of-the-mill edit suggestion:

- If it's good, accept it.
- If it's bad, reject it.
- If you're unsure (and you're in a review queue), skip it and let someone else have a go with it.

As ever, err on the side of caution.  If it looks like it's adding info that the OP may know, reject it anyway and comment on the question to really check if the OP hadn't logged into their account.

Comment: My point is that they will fill in information for which you have no idea if it's good or bad, like "I tried your suggestion, and now I'm having this problem." If it's not the same username, it's not clear whether someone _else_ or the OP made that edit.

Comment: Err on the side of caution. If it looks like it's adding more info but you're unsure it's from the OP, reject it anyway and leave a comment on the question.

Comment: It's not clear to me why you would answer with boilerplate and only add information specific to this question in a comment on the boilerplate answer.

Comment: @BoltClock I'm on my mobile.  I'll *happily* revise my answer with info from my comment.